# UITextField - Remove Ellipses on Text Overflow

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I have a UItextfieldthat holds a person's middle name.  I only want it to display the first initial, which it does, but i want it to hold their entire name.  It's only large enough to show the one initial, but it adds that ellipses (...) after the letter.Is it possible to remove those when a uitextfield overflows?  I haven't found anything online regarding someone with the same issue.

Thankyou for your help

Comment: Text field or UILabel ?

Comment: Why do you want to "hold their entire name" in a UITextField if you only want to display an initial?

Comment: I submit it up to a webservice after they "accept" it.  I want to display the initial only because it makes the UI way cleaner than putting the first, middle, and last name on different lines, and the user doesn't really need to know more than the initial.  And it is a UITextField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UITextField` shouldn't be truncating the text (because you can usually scroll/select that UI element).

A `UILabel` will truncate by default, you can set it to clip instead.

Answer (score 2):

I do see this truncation when the text field resigns first responder. I fixed this by setting the `lineBreakMode` in the NSParagraphStyle attribute to `.byClipping`. I happened to be using a subclass of UITextField so I overrode `resignFirstResponder()` to do this. My textField starts out empty so there is no attributedString to start with in viewDidLoad.

```
override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    guard let newAttributedText = (attributedText?.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableAttributedString) else {
        return super.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
    newAttributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText?.length ?? 0))
    attributedText = newAttributedText
    return super.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

This might not work if you set the text in code. In that case, you might want to set the `lineBreak` mode in a common function that you call from both the override of `resignFirstResponder()` and after setting the text in code. You could make a `set(text: String?)` function and call the common function from there.