# UITextField ellipsis in the middle of user input, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ellipsis

is it possible to have ellipsis in the middle of **UITextField**? Every answer I found was for UITextView. In my app I have textfield where user can paste his private key of his wallet, but its too long, and it gets cut at the end with three dots, what I would like to achive, since in private key, most important characters are first few and last few, to have something like this: `firstfewchar...lastfewchar`

Comment: do you have any suggestions? what would be most similar to textfield? @Sweeper problem is, that textfield is in our whole app, and we need to follow design, what would be best approach to fix this?

Comment: One way I can think of is, when the user stops editing the `UITextField`, put a `UILabel` on top of it, and set [`lineBreakMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620525-linebreakmode). Another idea is to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738285/uitextfield-remove-ellipses-on-text-overflow), but replace `byClipping` with `byTruncatingMiddle`. I'm not sure if that'll work.

Comment: I just tried it, and that answer does work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that by doing the following steps

1. Set the delegate methods to your textfield.
2. Create a new string attribute to store the original value the user pasted.
3. Define your own text cutting rule, and replace the current text of the textfield with the cut text when the user stops editing.
4. Replace the cut text with the original text when the user starts editing.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61762392/5133585), you should create your own custom `UITextField` subclass, and set the line break mode of the attributed text of the text field to `.byTruncatingMiddle`.

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {
    override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            makeTextTruncateInMiddle()
        }
    }
    
    private func makeTextTruncateInMiddle() {
        guard let newAttributedText = (attributedText?.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableAttributedString) else {
            return
        }
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle
        newAttributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText?.length ?? 0))
        attributedText = newAttributedText
    }
    
    override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        makeTextTruncateInMiddle()
        return super.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

The line break mode will be applied when the user stops editing the text field:

[image]

Comment: I am getting error for overrideing text: "Overriding non-@objc declarations from extensions is not supported"

Comment: @miki You should make your own text field subclass, not an extension.

Comment: @miki Nowhere in my answer have I said to use an extension, by the way.